# Modify SonicWALL Global VPN Client Encrypted RCF

Tags: vpn, encryption, sonicwall

Presently rolling out VPN to access to a small office.  I am using a SonicWALL TZ-170 running SonicOS Enhanced 3.4.1.0-2e.  I've created an encrypted RCF file for the clients to import into the SonicWALL Global VPN Client.

Is there a way to provide friendly names for the "Connection Name" and "HostName" in the RCF file?  If I create an unencrypted RFC file I can easily modify these values.  Is there anyway to modify them in an encrypted RCF file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like this is possible using the TZ-170.  I was also unable to find the encryption method by Serg's suggestions.